# Limit of the series $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a  be a strictly increasing sequence of positive real number with limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} = (\sqrt{2})^{e}$ and let $s_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n$.  If $\{x_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of real numbers with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = (e)^{\sqrt2}$, then find the value of
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k$$

I tried to calculate. Will it converge to $(\sqrt{2})^{e}(e)^{\sqrt2}$?

Comment: *If* $a_n=(\sqrt{2})^{e}$ and  $x_n = e^{\sqrt2}$ for all $n$ then $s_n=n(\sqrt{2})^{e}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k = n(\sqrt{2})^{e}e^{\sqrt2}$ so $\frac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k = e^{\sqrt2}$.  Thus, if there is a limit in general then it must be  $e^{\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following case of [Cesaro-Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) theorem:

- $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n \nearrow +\infty$
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n x_n}{a_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = e^{\sqrt{2}}$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k = e^{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks trancelocation. It was a direct consequence of Cesaro-Stolz theorem.

Comment: You are welcome.